# Numpy 4d array mask binarisation based on threshold value

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, mask

I have an image which is a 4d numpy array. I'm trying to make a mask based on a threshold value. This is based upon the first 4d array as shown below (40 percent of the mean). So I want to zero everything below this value to make the mask. I have some code below but when I've ave the nifti image the mask looks wrong. Please can anyone point as to why? Do I have to normalise the numpy array first to [0 1]? Thank you

```
  mean =  np.mean(im_aray[:,:,:,0])
  threshold = 0.4 * mean_echo1
  idx = im_array[:,:,:,0] < threshold
  mask = np.ones(np.shape(im_array))
  mask[idx,0] = threshold
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to first normalize the image and then calculate the threshold and so on.

```
  im_array = im_array / np.max(im_array)
  mean_echo1 = np.mean(im_array[:, :, :, 0])
  threshold = 0.4 * mean_echo1

  # Create an index array where all the voxels with intensity values below the
  # threshold are set to True.
  idx = im_array[:, :, :, 0] < threshold

  # Create a mask where all the voxels with intensity values below the threshold
  # are set to 0, and all the other voxels are set to 1.
  mask = np.ones(np.shape(im_array))
  mask[idx] = 0
```